# Pyparsing in Azure HDInsight

Tags: azure, pyparsing, azure-hdinsight, cortana-intelligence

**Is there a way to use Pyparsing in Azure HDInsight? If not is there a way to Install the Pyparsing package while creating the HDInsight cluster**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By design, pyparsing has an extremely small footprint, just a single Python file! If you are unable to install pyparsing, you can download the source and then save the single pyparsing file in with your own Python source code.

Comment: Make Sense Paul. And thank you very much for the parser code. On a other note, I'm trying to use the select_parser.py that you have posted and I'm not getting the expected out put while parsing tables when there are joins involved in the sql. Can you please shed some light on this.

Comment: That sounds like a different question, and you'll need to post some sample SQL and what results you are/aren't getting. One thing, JOIN syntax can be very database product specific. select_parser was written to line up with SQLite's syntax.

Comment: I'm trying to test the below <br/> <br/>      tests = """\
    select * from emp left join stud  on emp.emp.id = stud.emp.id
    select * from d a left join e b on a.a = b.a""".splitlines()  <br/><br/> And I'm not getting both the tables that I've used in my queries. <br/> <br/> The results I get for the tables or [stud] for the first query and [b] for the second one.

Comment: Please post as a new question - SO does not like long discussion threads in comments.  Then you can format things better too.

Comment: On line 61 of select_parser.py, replace `identifier` with `delimitedList(identifier,delim='.', combine=True)`.